# Spinner breaking fullscreen/immersive flags

Tags: android

In my app i have fullscreen mode requirement , to accomplish this

i have set

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in my activity.

But when i click on my spinner the navigation bar on the bottom becomes visible

[image]

I have also tried using a FullscreenActivity,

> Android Studio >Select “New” > Select “Activity” > "Fullscreen
>   Activity”.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @MattPennington nope, you can follow the updates on this issue here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68031.  

Its a known bug.

Comment: no news for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally, the solution for this issue was found by [kakajika](https://gist.github.com/kakajika/a236ba721a5c0ad3c1446e16a7423a63) and posted by Quinn [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60462764/9738227):

```
import android.widget.ListPopupWindow;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public static void avoidSpinnerDropdownFocus(Spinner spinner) {
    try {
        Field listPopupField = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        listPopupField.setAccessible(true);
        Object listPopup = listPopupField.get(spinner);
        if (listPopup instanceof ListPopupWindow) {
            Field popupField = ListPopupWindow.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
            popupField.setAccessible(true);
            Object popup = popupField.get((ListPopupWindow) listPopup);
            if (popup instanceof PopupWindow) {
                ((PopupWindow) popup).setFocusable(false);
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On the [linked Gits](https://gist.github.com/kakajika/a236ba721a5c0ad3c1446e16a7423a63) is the solution written also in Kotlin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60541031/3518278